# Kaniko on Kubernetes with github context

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kaniko

There is this example how to use git with kaniko image build :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
#  automountServiceAccountToken: false
  containers:
    - name: kaniko
      image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest
      args: [ "--dockerfile=kaniko/dockerfile/Dockerfile",
              "--context=git://github.com/scriptcamp/kubernetes-kaniko",`enter code here`
```

I tried to use my git project with dockerfile NOT in root of git project and also with specifying git branch.

It would help if Kaniko-setups could be included in "real" projects. Not possible ??

**EDIT :**

[image]

Here : --dockerfile=kaniko/dockerfile/Dockerfile
Kaniko docker build can find Dockerfile. But the build seems not to be able to find other files that are in the same directory (or below) , that Dockerfile build tries to copy to image being built.

This works if Dockerfile and other files that Dockerfile point to, all are at the root of gitbub repository.

**EDIT 2 :**

OK. If [kube/restapi/docker/] Dockerfile that docker-compose uses looks like this :

```
FROM openjdk:11

ARG JAR_FILE=./app.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Then if I would like to build this Dockerfile with Kaniko on Kubernetes, I have to add path from root of my project (and github repo), like this :

```
FROM openjdk:11

COPY kube/restapi/docker/app.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

-- I was very excited of the possibility to be able to use same Dockerfile both with docker-compose setup and with Kaniko on Kubernetes.

Hope that someone finds a way to "fix" this.

Comment: Could you add more details to your question, can you provide error prompts that you are receiving if any? Also, have you checked Google documentation on using [Kaniko](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/kaniko-cache) cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/issues/1064

spec.containers.args:

1. give "--context=git://github.com/...  (root of git repo)
2. give ***"--context-sub-path=path/to/setup/folder/"*** (starting from root of your project / github repo root)
3. give "--dockerfile=Dockerfile" (wich lives in context-sub-path)
4. give "--destination=..." - optional

Comment: Link is now to: https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#flag---context-sub-path